# Eclipse workspace as project's system root referece

Tags: linux, eclipse, perl

Is there a way to set up a project in Eclipse so that if my code has a reference to the system root directory then it will point to my workspace instead? (I am not seeing anything in the Run Configurations that would help me with this.) Something like the equivalent of making a sym link `/` that points to my workspace directory.

I'm working on a perl project that has absolute references to the hosting Linux file system in what would be the production environment. Those directories don't exist in my development Eclipse environment. My workspace is located in an NFS space mounted on a cluster of servers that run Eclipse I access in my laptop via client software.

So root can be any server's local space within the cluster and I don't have any access to anything above the workspace, and so I can't create the directory structures I need.  I would rather not hard-code alternate directory paths to accommodate differences between the sandbox and production environments and having to comment them out when deploying to the prod environment.

I'm not finding a straightforward answer online. Maybe I'm not articulating the question correctly and help with that would also be appreciated if that is the case.

Comment: What you had is sometimes called "wall of text."  It can be difficult to decide to delve into all that and read.  I broke it up, along with a couple of other minor edits related to long and somewhat winding sentences; please go through it to check how it reads. (If you don't like this you can "rollback" to a previous version, after you click on "edited ..." link above my username)

Answer (score 2):

No. Good practice is to have paths like that configurable at runtime, usually via an environment variable or command line argument, specifically to accommodate changes between development, sandbox, and production environments.